# Difficulties installing jekyll-polyglot: "Could not find gem 'helper x86_64-darwin-19'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

I'm new to Jekyll and I'm having a hard time installing the jekyll-polyglot plugin. My latest issues is the following, when trying to run "bundle exec" in the terminal. What is this 'helper x86_64-darwin-19'?

```
xxxx-xx:sebl xxxxx$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Could not find gem 'helper x86_64-darwin-19' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

If I run `bundle exec jekyll serve`, this is what I currently get:

````
Alessandros-Air:sebl alessandrolodola$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /Users/alessandrolodola/Desktop/SEBL/_config.yml
/Users/alessandrolodola/Desktop/SEBL/_plugins/polyglot-master/lib/jekyll/polyglot/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Jekyll::Polyglot::VERSION
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-polyglot-1.3.3/lib/jekyll/polyglot/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have /Users/alessandrolodola/Desktop/SEBL/_plugins/polyglot-master/spec/rspec/helper.rb or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. If you've run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, ensure that you have included the /Users/alessandrolodola/Desktop/SEBL/_plugins/polyglot-master/spec/rspec/helper.rb gem in your Gemfile as well. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- rspec' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/! 
                    ------------------------------------------------
      Jekyll 4.2.0   Please append `--trace` to the `serve` command 
                     for any additional information or backtrace. 
                    ------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:73:in `rescue in block in require_with_graceful_fail': /Users/alessandrolodola/Desktop/SEBL/_plugins/polyglot-master/spec/rspec/helper.rb (Jekyll::Errors::MissingDependencyException)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:58:in `block in require_with_graceful_fail'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:57:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:57:in `require_with_graceful_fail'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:89:in `block in require_plugin_files'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:87:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:87:in `require_plugin_files'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:21:in `conscientious_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:131:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:36:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:497:in `exec'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/Users/alessandrolodola/Desktop/SEBL/_plugins/polyglot-master/spec/rspec/helper.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rspec (LoadError)
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/Desktop/SEBL/_plugins/polyglot-master/spec/rspec/helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:60:in `block in require_with_graceful_fail'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:57:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/external.rb:57:in `require_with_graceful_fail'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:89:in `block in require_plugin_files'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:87:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:87:in `require_plugin_files'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:21:in `conscientious_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:131:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:36:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:497:in `exec'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/alessandrolodola/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```
````

Comment: Looks like you're not the only one with [that error](https://github.com/rubyjs/libv8/issues/290). I've noticed a few warnings with i18n since upgrading to Jekyll 4.2 on my sites. You might try Jekyll 4.1.1 and see if that works for your use case.

Comment: Thanks. I have since a far greater problem. I can't create any new site because the terminal doesn't recognize jekyll command line. I've tried ``` gem uninstall -all```to try a clean reinstallation but no luck... and I don't understand why. Something stupid I guess

Answer (score 0):

hi i also got this issue
[image]

same as yours

**Solution_is_very_simple**

```
bundle 
bundle add webrick
jekyll serve --watch --port 3200
```

[image]

Run these commands then your problem will be solved